# Create/Copy (this rule on all accounts) outlook using vba

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2016

Is there any way to copy outlook rule of one account to another account using vba code. I have researched on internet i have not found any thing related to my question, Pls help me. refer any link. I am not expert much of vba.I will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

See [Import or export a set of rules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-export-a-set-of-rules-F54B5BD2-40E0-426E-9F25-E51FA14EEB95).

You can create rules programmatically. The [Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/rules-create-method-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the `Rules` class creates a `Rule` object with the name specified by `Name` and the type of rule specified by `RuleType`. The `RuleType` parameter of the added rule determines valid rule actions, rule conditions, and rule exception conditions that can be associated with the `Rule` object. When a rule is added to the collection, the `Rule.ExecutionOrder` of the new rule is 1. The `ExecutionOrder` of other rules in the collection is incremented by 1.

```
 Sub CreateRule() 
   Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules 
   Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule 
   Dim colRuleActions As Outlook.RuleActions 
   Dim oMoveRuleAction As Outlook.MoveOrCopyRuleAction 
   Dim oFromCondition As Outlook.ToOrFromRuleCondition 
   Dim oExceptSubject As Outlook.TextRuleCondition 
   Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder 
   Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder 
   'Specify target folder for rule move action 
   Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
   'Assume that target folder already exists 
   Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Dan") 
   'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object 
   Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules() 
   'Create the rule by adding a Receive Rule to Rules collection 
   Set oRule = colRules.Create("Eugene's rule", olRuleReceive) 
   'Specify the condition in a ToOrFromRuleCondition object 
   'Condition is if the message is sent by "DanWilson" 
   Set oFromCondition = oRule.Conditions.From 
   With oFromCondition 
    .Enabled = True 
    .Recipients.Add ("Eugene Astafiev") 
    .Recipients.ResolveAll 
   End With 

   'Specify the action in a MoveOrCopyRuleAction object 
   'Action is to move the message to the target folder 
   Set oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder 
   With oMoveRuleAction 
    .Enabled = True 
    .Folder = oMoveTarget 
   End With 

   'Specify the exception condition for the subject in a TextRuleCondition object 
   'Exception condition is if the subject contains "fun" or "chat" 
   Set oExceptSubject = _ 
   oRule.Exceptions.Subject 
   With oExceptSubject 
    .Enabled = True 
    .Text = Array("fun", "chat") 
   End With 

   'Update the server and display progress dialog 
   colRules.Save 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Astagiev Can we copy the rules from one account to other account.I don't want to use import to export functionality.

Comment: Are you talking about client-side rules?

Comment: Yes, I have 1 exchange account that contain Server side rules and I want to copy all Server side rules to my other local outlook accounts on as and when needed basis through a VBA module?

Comment: The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for server-side rules.

Comment: Ok, please help me with the VBA code to copy one account client-side rule to all client-side rules